# Error 404 not found when connecting to Apache James WebAdmin

Tags: java, mail-server, centos8, apache-james

I've managed to install and start Apache James.

When I try to connect on the WebAdmin it says:

```
{"statusCode":404,"type":"notFound","message":"GET / can not be found","details":null}
```

So I am not able to access the WebAdmin. I followed the official documentation... installing jdk 11, downloading JPA Guice binary, configuring and then run.

From documentation I understand that the only file conf for WebAdmin is conf/webadmin.properties but in this file there's only the parameters for port and host.